# Returning information from texture

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm trying to set up a clickable world map. I have a 4096x4096 png as a texture on a plane and the idea is to allow selecting different countries while keeping the geometry as simple as possible. It is now achieved by comparing the color for the projected mouse coordinates with the color of the texture. So in this case:

[image]

mouse over germany would give us 255,186,0. If the currently processed fragment is of this color, then that's what is returned, otherwise it defaults to the blue below. It works well, hovering over any country that has a color assigned changes its color (there's some minor accuracy issue but I hope to solve it).

The problem is however, the comparison is made in the shader. There is no way to return anything, so back in javascript I don't know whether or not something is hovered over. Without it I cannot display any information about the selected country. Is there a way to - for instance - come up with the information about the color of the country hovered over before going to shaders? I could then not only just send this information as a uniform but also use it on javascript level.

I can produce some code if needed but as everything I have so far actually works I'm unsure what to post.

Before anyone asks, yes I did consider setting every country up as a separate mesh but it would not only take significantly more time but would also be far worse performance-wise (it has to run on below average machines).

Comment: Just render map color to a texture and then look up a color at mouse coordinate with [gl.readPixels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/readPixels) (you will need to transform mouse coords though). Then, having pixel color you could perform the same operation you do in shader.

Comment: You can make the FBO  very small size that just surrounds the mouse position and only read very few pixels back. To make that work you have to be careful with math to get translation/scaling right for your vertex shader. It will save memory bandwidth which can be problem in some portable devices.

Comment: @mlkn this is probably what I'm looking for - the problem is that it always returns zeroes.